# Cursor in text box appears on top of drop down menu in IE8/9

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/simply_simpy/kkf3A/3/

1. Use IE 8/9 and click in the input text box.
2. Hover over 'industries'
3. Notice the cursor appears on top of the drop down menu.
4. Same issue if you hover over business/business.

I am trying to find a html/css solution and avoid JS.

Thanks!

Comment: This is defiantly an odd one. I tried tweaking z-indexs .. I messed around with input:blur Where I tried changing the cursor to white using css on blur. Still no luck. I hate to say it, but its starting to look like javascript might be the best option.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck -- I think you maybe right, I am working on a JS solution now.

Comment: I have a JS solution reflected here: http://jsfiddle.net/simply_simpy/hMTMq/3/ . But if anyone can figure out the bug, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This is seem to be odd bug. However, try the JS solution

1. Add an #id of "search" to the input text box.
2. Add below to your jQuery inside the "ready" function.

   $('.dropdown a').hover(function(){
       $("#search").blur();
   });